# How can we define a covariant $k$-tensor this way if tensors are already defined by the tensor product?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, definition, tensor-products

> From Lee's *Intro to Smooth Manifolds*:[image]

---

If we take $k$ covectors, $\varepsilon^{i_1}, \dots, \varepsilon^{i_k},$ then the tensor product is defined by $$\varepsilon^{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes \varepsilon^{i_k}(v_1, \dots, v_k)=\varepsilon^{i_1}(v_1)\cdots \varepsilon^{i_k}(v_k).$$

So, how can we define a covariant $k$-tensor as in the image above?

Comment: As you've noticed, $\epsilon^I$ is not the tensor product of $\epsilon^{i_1}\cdots \epsilon^{i_k}$, however it is a multilinear map from $V$ to $k$, and thus corresponds to an element of $V^{*\otimes k}$.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? If the question is obvious to you, it may not be obvious to others.

Comment: while I am not the downvoter, I figured I'd offer my thoughts, since my earlier comment resulted in me receiving a notification about your comment. I suspect the reason this question was downvoted is that it doesn't show very much research or effort. After all, you posted an image with two sentences that don't really explain what you found confusing. You also ignored my comment (from 3 days ago) attempting to answer your question (which may have factored into a negative perception of your question, though I'm unbothered by it).

Answer (score 2):

You define it as shown, as there is no conflict of definitions. Perhaps the $k = 2$ case can render a bit more readability.

Although

$$ \varepsilon ^ {i_1} \otimes \varepsilon ^ {i_2}, \varepsilon^{(i_1,i_2)}:V^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

have the same domain and codomain, they are defined entirely differently, as shown in your post:

$$\varepsilon^{i_1}\otimes\varepsilon^{i_2}(v_1,v_2) =  \varepsilon^{i_1}(v_1) \varepsilon^{i_2}(v_2)$$

$$\varepsilon^{(i_1,i_2)}(v_1,v_2) = \varepsilon^{i_1}(v_1)\varepsilon^{i_2}(v_2) - \varepsilon^{i_1}(v_2)\varepsilon^{i_2}(v_1)$$